# MultiStorage file content in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a directory with files with somewhat mailformatted logs (NEWLINE delimited), I want to select specific position in each row and use it as a directory/file name

code below works just file and does what I expect, the problem is that the substring is now  inside of the new file, is there a way to store B$1 in the file use B$0 as a file name meaning preserve the original files content as is?

```
REGISTER /lib/pig/piggybank.jar;

A = LOAD '/raw/*' USING PigStorage('\n') AS (mytext:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE SUBSTRING(mytext,5,7), mytext;
STORE B INTO '/output' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('/output', '0', 'none', ' ') ;
```

Comment: Do you want `SUBSTRING(mytext, 5, 5)` in one file and `mytext` in a different one?

Comment: I would like SUBSTRING(mytext, 5, 5) to be directory/file name and mytext the content, the example I posted does SUBSTRING(mytext, 5, 5) as directory/file name but the content is "SUBSTRING(mytext, 5, 5) mystring" meaning the tuple is the content, not just mytext

Comment: try adding `MultiStorage('/output', '0', 'none', ',')` to the end of your last line (i.e., add a comma to the last arguement) and also try naming `SUBSTRING(mytext, 5, 5)` something.  Like `SUBSTRING(mytext, 5, 5) as name_of_file:chararray`

Comment: tried both, did not help. Comma added a separator between two fields in  the file where first field is the content of SUBSTRING(mytext, 5, 7) and second mytext e.g. SA,THISISATEST  where file name is SA/SA-0000